# Confluent Replicator is creating topic in destination but not migrating topic messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

What are the things to check when the replicator is not migrating the topic messages from the source to destination?

- replicator pod logs dont have any errors
- replicator is creating the topic in the destination cluster from the source cluster
- I am able to produce messages from a kafka producer running on the same namespace
  as replicator
- Checked `__consumer_offsets` topic and I see that the
  messages are consumed from the source cluster.

replicator is also finding the topic. log has it.

```
[INFO] 2023-10-30 11:17:21,939 [topic-monitor-thread-replicator] io.confluent.connect.replicator.NewTopicMonitorThread listMatchingTopics - Found matching topics: [replicator-test-source, __consumer_timestamps]
```

The kafka server log also doesnt have error…

```
[2023-10-30 08:42:09,331] INFO [Admin Manager on Broker 201]: Updating topic replicator-test-source-1 with new configuration : message.timestamp.type -> CreateTime,segment.bytes -> 100000000,flush.messages -> 10000,unclean.leader.election.enable -> true,min.insync.replicas -> 2 (kafka.server.AdminManager) [2023-10-30 08:42:09,343] INFO Processing notification(s) to /config/changes (kafka.common.ZkNodeChangeNotificationListener) [2023-10-30 08:42:09,346] INFO Processing override for entityPath: topics/replicator-test-source-1 with config: Map(message.timestamp.type -> CreateTime, segment.bytes -> 100000000, flush.messages -> 10000, unclean.leader.election.enable -> true, min.insync.replicas -> 2) (kafka.server.DynamicConfigManager)
```

Replicator Config:

```
apiVersion: platform.confluent.io/v1beta1
kind: Connector
metadata:
  name: replicator
  namespace: destination
spec:
  name: replicator
  class: "io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector"
  taskMax: 4
  configs:
    topic.whitelist: "replicator-test-source-1"
    confluent.topic.replication.factor: "3"
    dest.kafka.bootstrap.servers: "<dest ip addresses>"
    dest.kafka.security.protocol: "SSL"
    dest.kafka.ssl.truststore.location: "/mnt/sslcerts/ssl-certs/truststore.jks"
    dest.kafka.truststore.password: "<dest truststore password>"
    dest.kafka.sasl.mechanism: "PLAIN"
    dest.kafka.sasl.jaas.config: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"admin\" password=\"<jass password>\";"
    dest.kafka.reconnect.backoff.ms: "600000"
    dest.kafka.request.timeout.ms: "600000"
    provenance.headetelr.enable: "true"
    key.converter: "io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter"
    src.consumer.group.id: "replicator-test-source-1-group"
    src.kafka.timestamps.topic.replication.factor: "3"
    src.kafka.sasl.mechanism: "PLAIN"
    src.kafka.ssl.truststore.location: "/mnt/sslcerts/ssl-certs/broker.jks"
    src.kafka.truststore.password: "<src trust store password>"
    src.kafka.bootstrap.servers: "<src ip addresses>"
    src.kafka.security.protocol: "SSL"
    value.converter: "io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter"
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: ""
    src.kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: ""
    dest.kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: ""
  connectRest:
    tls:
      secretRef: ssl-certs
```

Followed [Replicator Readme](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kubernetes-examples/blob/master/hybrid/replicator/README.md) to set up replicator in k8s